# how can i make disappear the list when i approached the NFC tag?

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

My problem is that when i approached the NFC tag, immediately appear a list with all the applications that i have developed for using NFC, i dont want that !!
I want that just one of this applications be launched with that specifically NFC tag.

The list that appear is this:
[image]

And i want that the application "NFC UidClass" be displayed, without show the list (I wont uninstall the other NFC applications). Something like this:
[image]

This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="true" />
```

Please someone help me. :)

Comment: The app chooser is appearing because multiple apps are responding to your intent. Do a bit of reading on how to write an intent that only your app will respond to when using NFC.

Comment: Thanks men! Its really help me!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use mime type. You could add an `intent-filter` `ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED` with a specific mime-type.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#mime

In your `AndroidManifest`:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.com.mycompany.data"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

For instance, to create tag with specific mime type:

```
NdefRecord mimeRecord = NdefRecord.createMime("application/vnd.com.mycompany.data",
    "some data".getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
```

Comment: Thanks men! Its really help me!! :D

Comment: I am new on stack overflow and i didn't know that the answer could be accepted. But now i did it! I really appreciate your time and your help! Have a nice day!!!